# How do you do tiling in opengl

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to make a rpg game, and I want to show a tiled map.

What I'm doing now is for each tile I calculate it's position, and if it is on visible area, I bind the texture, set the texture coordinates and draw a square using 2 triangles.

Everything worked quite fine but I find that I often get black lines between some tiles which is very annoying. How do you get rid of those black lines or is there some better way doing tiling using opengl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ofcourse very difficult for me to know what is causing the problem without any code or screenshots, but I can give my best guess. First of all, if your coordinates are tightly packed between the tiles there should NOT appear any cracks beetween the tiles. By tightly packed I mean that the bottom of a tile has the exact same Y coordinate value as the top of the tile below.

However, it might also be because of the texture repeating and the linear filtering giving you issues on the edge of the tile. If this is the case, you can solve it by using:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

If you turn of the texture does the cracks still appear? If so, there must be some geometric spacing between your tiles. Maybe something is rounded to int somewhere in your code or something?

These are my best guesses, but I suggest uploading a screenshot of the issue to maybe get a better answer. Best of luck!